# Do not drop sort mode for the next search

Tags: feature-request, search, sorting

Currently the every new search on the [search page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) drops sort mode to "relevance":

> [image: relevance]

Is it possible to leave sort mode unchanged when I only want to refine the search query?